# SSR Nuxt.js with integreted REST API backend

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm developing an SSR Nuxt.js app with an integrated REST API server.

To do this, I've added my `/api` endpoint inside Nuxt `server.js` code as following

```js
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')

const app = express()

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// MY REST API ENDPOINT (It's the right approach?)
const routesApi = require('./api/routes')
app.use('/api', routesApi)

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  await nuxt.ready()
  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

I didn't found examples related to this approach.

I need some help to understand if it's the right way.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: i wrote an blog article how to setup an rest api with nuxt https://blogxon.com/articles/basic-express-nuxt-api

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would probably like to read following article: https://blog.lichter.io/posts/nuxt-with-an-api/
It has common takes to solve "API with Nuxt" case.

Your solution is already enough for small integrated API, I guess, that way you avoid setting up proxy against CORS issues. :) You could add some sugar with `serverMiddleware`:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
...
  serverMiddleware: [
    '/api': '~/api/index.js'
  ],
...
}
```

```js
// api/index.js
export default function (req, res, next) {
  ... // Well, here comes nothing
  next()
}
```

But big API scales nice on separate server, it's also a separation of concerns to consider. Nuxt serves better as universal app rendering middleware, but API can be written even in another language, backend. For defying problems with CORS, you'll need to place `/api` on same domain, as you intended, thus it's more easier with [Nuxt proxy-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module).